# Laravel Policies - How to Pass Multiple Arguments to function

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-5

I'm trying to authorize a users character to delete/update post. I was using policies to do so, but I could only pass one parameter to the policy function. If I pass more than the user and another variable, the variable isn't passed into the function.

Models: User has many characters, a character can post multiple posts. So for authorization purposes, I would have to compare the post's character_id with the current character's id...-

Per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization), you can pass more multiples to the Gate Facade:

```
Gate::define('delete-comment', function ($user, $post, $comment) {
    //
});
```

But I couldn't find anyway to do so with policies. What I had to do was to inject the Request object to get the object needed for authorization. Basically I wouldn't even need the User Object.

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

Using the Request object works, but it feels very hacky. Is there a nicer way to achieve this?

edit:

In the `CharacterLocationController` I have a method `show` and I want to authorize the action before showing the resource.

```
public function show(Request $request, Character $character, Location $location)
{
    $this->authorize([$location, $character]);
    ...
}
```

The policy is registered like this: `'App\Location' => 'App\Policies\LocationPolicy'` in the `AuthServiceProvider`

I dumped the array passed to the policy function, and it only outputs the `$location`.

```
public function show(User $user, $data) {
    dd($data); // expecting location and character
    return !$location->private || $location->authorized->contains($this->character);
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think there is possibly some confusion here on what functions are doing what.

When you use

```
Gate::define('delete-comment', function ($user, $post, $comment) {
    //
});
```

Or in the `CommentPolicy`

```
public function delete(User $user, Post $post, Comment $comment)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

All you are doing is defining the rules.  At this point, we aren't worried about passing anything, only that the objects we received can or should be able to interact with each other.  The only difference between these two is when using policies, it's just an easy way to abstract all your rules into one simple and easy to read class.  If you have an app with potentially hundreds of tables and models, it will get confusing fast if you have these rules littered all over your app so policies would help to keep them all organized.

It's when you are actually checking if someone has permission to do something when you should be passing these items along.  For example, when you do the following,

```
if (Gate::allows('delete-comment', [$post, $comment])) {
    // 
}
```

Or if in the `CommentController`

```
$this->authorize('delete', [$post, $comment]);
```

That is what controls which parameters are going to be passed to the policy or the `Gate::define` method.  According to the docs, the `$user` parameter is already added for you so in this case, you only need to worry about passing the correct `$post` and `$comment` being modified.

Comment: Thanks for the clearification, although I still have one question left. The Policy itself is attached to a class (like a eloquent model), so the rule is automatically called, when passing an object of the proper type as the second paremter. If you pass an array, just as you did in the `CommentController` example, what policy is used then? Is it trying to resolve the first object in the passed array?

Comment: I did some testing and the docs seem to imply it will use multiple policies for each argument passed but I could only ever get the policy for the first item in the array to get called.

Comment: I didn't read the code for the policies yet. What's important to note is the order of the variables just as you said. It will call the policy for the first variable depending on its type.

Comment: @Johannes It looks like, according to the [code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/934ca73e7c1491e3f2ed459a8b8864eb2d46ded6/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L348-L352), only the first argument is inspected to find a policy.

Comment: What was stuffing me up was not passing the multiple extra args in an array. The Laravel docs could be a bit more detailed in this area. But v happy to find the problem.

Comment: Take care to add the class name to the array when the method doesn't require a model instance such as create, e.g. `$this->authorize('create', [Comment::class, $post]);`

Comment: @piscator Can i do the same with `authorizeResource()`?

Comment: The comment of @piscator is actually very useful and needed when dealing with policies (and storing according models) in many cases. OP maybe you could add this to your answer? Thank both of you anyways

Comment: @ThiagoPereira were you able to accomplish this with `authorizeResource()`?

Comment: @piscator legend! Stumbled on this after 2 hours of searching.