# Laravel: Get class name in policy

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing a general policy which which will apply on multiple Models. How can I retrieve the class name of the class which needs to be authorized?

Policies:

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\User' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Customer' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
];
```

The ModelPolicy:

```
class ModelPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function index(User $user){
        // how can I retrieve the class name, like User or Customer?
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is for example my customer controller. So in the policy I want to retrieve something like: App\Customer.

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $this->authorize('index', Customer::class);
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need custom gates.

In your controller:

```
$this->authorize('model-index', Appointment::first());
```

In AuthServiceProvider:

```
Gate::define('model-index', function ($user, $model) {
    var_dump(get_class($model));
    die();
});
```

This way you can take the parameters you need for your authorization methods.

Please see

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#gates

[Laravel Policies - How to Pass Multiple Arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482737/laravel-policies-how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-to-function)